# Unexpected change of position with a primefaces 5.0 panel

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi all I'm doing a sticky note system with primefaces 5, and those notes are overlapped from a image, the positions and the text of the note are saved in posgrest database.

Basically what I have done  till now is a dragable text area that takes some of css values from the database, But I have a problem when I save the data in the database the note come back to the 0,0 position and is not more dragable, you have to reload the page. I save the values using the event blur.

that is what is happening 
how the postConstruct load the elements in the screen its ok
[image]
And this is what happen after saving the changes, but in the database all is saved well.
[image]

This is my code

The xhtml File

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>


</h:head>
<h:body>

<h:form id="notesForm">

    <p:panel id="board">
     <h:graphicImage library="images" name="prime.png"
            style="z-index:-100">
        </h:graphicImage>
        <p:dataList value="#{anotationBean.listanotationModel}"
            var="anotation" type="definition">

            <p:panel id="opnl"
                style="background: transparent; padding: 0px; width: 180px; height:10px; top:#{anotation.posy}; left:#{anotation.posx}">
                <p:ajax event="close" listener="#{anotationBean.onClose}" />
                <p:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="30" value="#{anotation.text}"
                    style="width: 80%; height:80%; background-color:#{anotation.bodycolor};color:#{anotation.fontcolor};  ">
                    <p:ajax event="blur" update="opnl"
                        listener="#{anotationBean.saveAnotation(anotation)}" />
                </p:inputTextarea>


            </p:panel>
            <p:resizable for="opnl" minWidth="100" minHeight="100" />
            <p:draggable for="opnl" opacity="0.3" />

        </p:dataList>


    </p:panel>


</h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your time and answers, I really apreciate sugestions to improve the behavior of my code

Comment: You do realize that you have multiple panels with the id opnl ?.. my suggestion is to start from this point.. generate unique id's .. and update them .. I'm not sure after updating them how you would maintain the position of the elements (dragged).. I think you should maintain them and after the update, you should update the positions also.
OR just save the annotation by the blur event and discard the update="opnl".. is seems unnecessary for me. and another point maybe you should put the resizable and draggable tags inside the panel (if you have to update the panel)

Comment: Hi I tryed to set the panel id usig the database id atribue, this way id="#{anotation.id}" but I was getting this error: Empty id attribute is not allowed, so i decided to use a fixed id, knowing that jsf will generate diferents id. About the other point I have to save the new position always that the element is dragged, and that is another problem I think if I have top:#{anotation.posy};left:#{anotation.posx} the bean should be updated but that is not happening, I ask you for help in this poing. And your sugestion of put the resizable and draggable tags actually solved my problem. Thanks